# JQuery .on('click'... issue referencing list-group-items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am writing a large website and I got stuck referencing a small navigation bar. I am using Twitter Bootstrap.

I'm sure I'm missing something novice. This is the JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ugdh2jmL/2/. I'm going to be referencing a series of dynamically loaded list objects. I can add them easily but I'm having issues declaring an onclick event; nothing happens, no message, nothing.

Here are the snippets:

```js
$('.list-group').on('click', '.list-group-item', function(e) {
  alert('success');
}):
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="list-group">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
```

Comment: You need to include jquery.js

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/ugdh2jmL/4/

Comment: The problem with your script is the **:** at the end instead of an **;**

Comment: @nikhil.agw even if you include jQuery in OP's fiddle, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Guys.... @nikhil.agw beat you to it and I know its not great code. Its not like I'm using that exact snippet in my website :P Its just a representation of what I wanted. Please stop taking a dump on me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For code to trigger you need to include jquery library as well.

I have also updated fiddle.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).on('click', '.list-group', function(e){
    alert('success');
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ugdh2jmL/3/

Comment: Are you kidding me.... I'm going to cry in the corner with my B.S. in CS now.. http://media.giphy.com/media/8WdsK61D9YOOc/giphy.gif

Answer (score 0):

Missing jQuery and `:` should be `;`

```js
$('.list-group').on('click', '.list-group-item', function(e) {
  alert('success');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4">
        <div class="list-group">
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <h4 class="list-group-item-heading">List group item heading</h4>
            <p class="list-group-item-text">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget risus varius blandit.</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- /.col-sm-4 -->
```